# Emacs - Failed to change cursor-type and cursor-color

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am using emacs in mac OS X terminal. I tried to put these codes in my init.el file:

```
(setq-default cursor-type '(bar . 1))                                                                                                                                                                  
(set-cursor-color "#7AA3CC")
```

But the cursor still looks the same. I am not sure is it the default setting of mac os.

Comment: In a recent unrelated thread, it became apparent that certain versions of Emacs for OSX do not support the entire rainbow. How about trying something simple, like "yellow" or "blue", just in case you are experiencing the inability to select every color in the rainbow. I'm not a terminal user, but I believe there are also limitations to the color spectrum when using a terminal versus the GUI -- I recall reading something about the number 256 . . . something-or-other.

Comment: Did you restart emacs after you have added these lines?

Comment: @lawlist, I tried both yellow and blue, nothing happened!

Comment: @Adobe, yes I always reload init.el, but it seems not working.

Comment: *On a text terminal, the cursor's appearance is controlled by the terminal, largely out of the control of Emacs. Some terminals offer two different cursors: a “visible” static cursor, and a “very visible” blinking cursor. By default, Emacs uses the very visible cursor, and switches to it when you start or resume Emacs. If the variable visible-cursor is nil when Emacs starts or resumes, it uses the normal cursor.  On a graphical display, many more properties of the text cursor can be altered.*  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html

Answer (score -2):

i did a check on you code. and all worked well, on linux and windows versions.
so just check if u are editing the correct init file.

open you emacs and do C-x C-f ~/.emacs , type you code and save. C-x C-s.

you can change the color and the cursor, if u want in the session that u have, just pres M-x and enter you code.

Comment: This does not address OP's comment that the failure is on a Mac OS X terminal.